# two different output in different console with same code in c?

Tags: c, console

"getting different output in different console with the same code. I have used gcc compiler in vs code and dev c++ uses system compiler."

````
```C programming 

int main()
{

int a=0;
int arr[a];

int i;
printf("enter the size of array:"); 
scanf("%d",&a);
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    printf("enter a %d no",i);
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}
return 0;
}

```
````

Comment: Please post code here as text.

Comment: Post your code, not an image of it.

Comment: @TomKarzes I like your style :-)

Answer (score 1):

The defect is that you declare `int arr[a]` (latter is a VLA) when `a` has been initialized to `0`.  This means no memory is allocated to `arr`, and when you write to it (via `scanf`) you undefined behavior.

You *can* use `int arr[a];` if you declare it after you read the value of `a`.  The problem is that there is no way to check for stack overflow (i.e. try set `a` to >8192 or whatever your stack size is set to and see what happens).

Try something along these lines:

```
unsigned a;
printf("enter size of array: ");
if(scanf("%u", &a) <= 0 || a == 0) {
  // error handling
}

int *arr = malloc(a * sizeof(int));
if(!arr) {
  // error handling
}
```

Use unsigned type for the variable `a` that holds a size and check that it's `> 0` (I believe malloc(0) is not well defined on some platforms; on Linux it would cause malloc to return NULL hence trigger an error handling in the above code).  Check all return codes for errors.

Comment: Please don't encourage "pictures of code" questions by answering them.

Comment: I figured op would fix the question by the time I finished the answer.  Btw, is there anything that we do for people deleting their question?  It's particular annoying when I in the middle of answering.

Comment: Don't answer bad questions until they get fixed...?